# how does q combine dictionary outputs to create table when each is used?

Tags: kdb

```
time_snap_temp:((1 2 3 4);(4 5 6 7);(7 8 9 10))
col_names:`AA`AB`AC`AD
f_try: {y!x}[;col_names]
agg:f_try each time_snap_temp
one_dict: f_try time_snap_temp[0]
```

one_dict is a dictionary as expected but agg is a table. How does q combine dictionaries to create a table in agg?

Thanks and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table is actually a list of dictionaries, when using `f_try` with each it will output a list of dictionaries which get promoted to a table. When just using `f_try` with the first entry in `time_snap_temp`, just one dictionary is outputted so remains a dictionary.

```
// see how using 1# and each here will output list of dictionaries of length 1 and also get promoted to a table
q)f_try each 1#time_snap_temp
AA AB AC AD
-----------
1  2  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

A table is a list of *like* dictionaries; that is, dictionaries with the same key. (Key order matters.)

`f_try` could be a simple projection of [Dict](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dict/) `!`:

```
q)f_try:`AA`AB`AC`AD!
q)f_try each time_snap_temp
AA AB AC AD
-----------
1  2  3  4
4  5  6  7
7  8  9  10
```

Or just use Dict [Each Right](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right) `/:`

```
q)`AA`AB`AC`AD!/:time_snap_temp / key is constant
AA AB AC AD
-----------
1  2  3  4
4  5  6  7
7  8  9  10
```

But if the keys don’t match

```
q)4 4 4?\:col_names  / mix up the keys: Deal Each Left
AC AC AD AC
AA AB AB AC
AD AD AC AB
q)(4 4 4?\:col_names)!'time_snap_temp
`AC`AD`AD`AA!1 2 3 4
`AC`AB`AA`AB!4 5 6 7
`AA`AD`AD`AD!7 8 9 10
```

If the keys are not identical, the list is just a list of dictionaries. They must be *like* dictionaries to yield a table.

With a matrix you don’t need to iterate through the rows like this. You can flip it, use Dict to make a column dictionary ( dictionary of same-length columns) and flip back into a table. (The [`flip`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/flip/) keyword just sets an internal flag, so it is a cheap operation.)

```
q)flip `AA`AB`AC`AD!flip time_snap_temp
AA AB AC AD
-----------
1  2  3  4
4  5  6  7
7  8  9  10
```